# auto.arima model with many regressors

Tags: time-series, forecasting, feature-selection, arima, dynamic-regression

I am trying to forecast a seasonal series with 30 regressors using auto.arima.
I have several questions regarding the correct methodology that I need to pursue.

1) Should I fit auto.arima with all available regressors and pick those regressors with significant t-statistics?

2) Should I fit regressors one by one (and all combinations) with auto.arima and pick the model with the lowest AIC?

3) Should I use PLS (partial least squares, supervised) to reduce the dimension of regressors first and only use relevant ones as regressors with auto.arima?

4) Should I use PCA (principal component analysis, unsupervised) to reduce the dimension of regressors first and only use relevant ones as regressors with auto.arima?

Thank you in advance for your guidance.
Arsa

Comment: Option (3) is the closest to a good solution, IMHO.

Comment: If you want to check all combinations of 30 regressors per (2), you will need to run $2^{30}=1073741824$ different models. I hope you have a lot of time.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, and then there is the winner's curse as in [Hansen (2010)](https://sites.google.com/site/peterreinhardhansen/research-papers/awinnerscurseforeconometricmodelsonthejointdistributionofin-samplefitandout-of-samplefitanditsimplicationsformodelselection/InOutSlides2010.pdf). By the way, 30 regressors is still fine w.r.t. computational time for branch-and-bound type of algorithms in linear regression, but without ARMA errors, though.

Comment: 1) I would recommend reading [Statistical tests for variable selection](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) <br> 2) I liked Stephen Kolassa's comment <br> 3) I am curious how this really work, I don't have experience with this. How would the partial least squares model look like ? <br> 4) never bad idea to reduce dimensionality beforehand <br> 5) I am currenyly solving similar problem and considering reducing the regressors via Granger test, not sure how it will go though

Comment: PLS and PCA results have been practically very close (PLS has slightly better explanatory capability). Still working on (parallelization + GPU) of option 2... Thanks much by the way for your insights...